# 3rd Galois cohomology of $n$th root of unity vanishes

Tags: group-cohomology, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

I'm reading Milne's class field theory, and there is a statement about a group cohomology which I cannot understand. Let $K$ be a field and $K^{sep}$ be a separable algebraic closure of $K$, and let $G=Gal(K^{sep}/K)$. Then we can regard $\mu_n$, the group of $n$th root of unity, as $G$-module. The book saids that from the cohomology sequence of $$0\to\mu_n\to (K^{sep})^{\times} \xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^{n}} (K^{sep})^{\times}\to 0$$ we get $$K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^{n}\simeq H^{1}(G, \mu_n),\,\,\,\,H^{2}(G, \mu_n)\simeq H^{2}(G, (K^{sep})^{\times})[n].$$
I understand that the first isomorphism comes from Hilbert's theorem 90, but I don't know why the second holds. I think we need to show $$H^{3}(G, \mu_{n})=0$$ for the second one but the book does not contain any information about it. How to show this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write $L$ for $K^{\text{sep}}$ and $H^n(A)$ for $H^n(G,A)$.

Part of the exact sequence is
$$H^1(L^\times)\to H^2(\mu_n)\to H^2(L^\times)\to H^2(L^\times).$$
By Hilbert 90, $H^1(L^\times)=0$ so this is
$$0\to H^2(\mu_n)\to H^2(L^\times)\to H^2(L^\times).$$
Therefore $H^2(G,\mu_n)$ is the kernel of multiplication by $n$
on $H^2(G,(K^{\text{sep}})^\times)$.

Not an $H^3$ in sight!

Comment: Thank you very much. I always confuse about long exact sequences...maybe I'm only familiar with short exact sequences. By the way, can we compute the cohomology group $H^{3}(\mu_{n})$? Just curious.